# Azure Storage Javascript SDK V12 creating append blob issue

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-node-sdk

When I create manually append blob in portal and try this:

```
const blockBlobClient = containerClient.getAppendBlobClient('appendtest.csv');
const uploadBlobResponse = await blockBlobClient.appendBlock('test,','test,'.length);
```

works like a charm.

But If I try:

```
const blockBlobClient = containerClient.uploadBlockBlob('appendtest2.csv','test,','test,'.length, {"x-ms-blob-type":"AppendBlob"});
const uploadBlobResponse = await blockBlobClient.appendBlock('test,','test,'.length);
```

I get error that blob is not of supported type.

Answer (score 0):

After digging through Type definitions this solved the issue:

```
const blockBlobClient = await containerClient.getAppendBlobClient('appendtest5.csv');
const createresponse = await blockBlobClient.create();
const uploadBlobResponse = await blockBlobClient.appendBlock('test,','test,'.length);
```